# windows server RDP works but c$ shared folder access denied

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block

this might be something simple, but I think I rather ask here.

We have some servers in our environment which are in workgroup, they can ping each other, test-wsman is a success, RDP from one to another works, BUT from server1 I cannot open \\server2\c$ - it asks for credentials and then says access denied. The same credentials work in RDP and I have the same username and pwd on both servers. I wonder if it was a network problem I would get "network error - windows cannot access", rather then straight access denied.
invoke-command also does not work and says the WinRM client cannot process the request.
if I look in secpol.msc / local policies / user rights assignment / access this computer from the network - the administrators group is listed and my account is member of local administrators.
What canbe the issue here?

Comment: This is by design - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction

Answer (score 0):

so it seems like this settings is the problem! File and printer sharing is off on those servers

[image]